# How does .NET know which endpoint is the request to WEBAPI

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, webapi

For example, I have a .NET WEB API project and it provide  the following endpoints

```
1- /api/controller1/{id}

2- /api/controller1/{id}/summary

3- /api/controller1/{name}/{surname}
```

I send request with postman as below

```
http://localhost:5001/api/controller1/5/summary
```

How does aspnetcore know that it will enter the 2nd endpoint? I looked through the aspnetcore code but couldn't find it.

Comment: It's called "routing". You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Answer (score 1):

So in nutshell it is called routing. So routing is the process of mapping the incoming HTTP Request (URL) to a particular resource.
So it works like this , so first of all you need to configure routes for your application.
Routes can be

1. **Conventional** : Conventions that are defined in route templates that, at runtime, will map requests to controllers and actions (methods).
2. **Attribute-based routing**: The route is determined based on attributes that you set on your controllers and methods.

So after you have configured routing in your application and you run your application, then

1. It will create the Route table and the Route table will contain the mapping information between the URL and the Resource.
2. When we are sending a request from the client to the server, then the application will check the URL in the Route table and if it found an exact, then the application will forward the request to that particular resource else it will throw an error saying resource not found.

So in your example http://localhost:5001/api/controller1/5/summary, you will have routing placed like this in one of your action method.

```
[Route("{id:int}/summary")]
public public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSummary(int id)
{
}
```

So when the above URL is requested , it will go to controller1 and see if we have any action method which matches the route. When it gets it will execute that action method.

**Next question is why does it bind with /api/controller1/{id}/summary and not /api/controller1/{name}/{surname}.**

So we have concept of Route Constraint. So suppose you have following action methods in your controller.

```
    [Route("{id}/summary")]
        public string GetSummary(int Id)
        {
            
        }
        [Route("{name}/summary")]                                
public string GetSummary(string name)
        {
            
        }
```

Now if you call the above URL (http://localhost:5001/api/controller1/5/summary), it will not work and will give you error "*The request matches multiple endpoints*".This is because, when the request comes, the application does not identify which version of the GetSummary() method to use, and hence it gives an Ambiguous Match Exception as two end points match the same request.

To resolve this we can use Route Constraints. Route Constraint restrict how the parameters in the route template are matched. The syntax is like this **{parameter:constraint}**. We can use the type constraint to specify the parameter type. So now we can have two action method like this

```
         [Route("{id:int}/summary")]
            public string GetSummary(int Id)
            {
                
            }

            [Route("{name}/summary")]     
           public string GetSummary(string name)
        {
            
        }
```

So now if you go to the URL(http://localhost:5001/api/controller1/5/summary) it matches with the GetSummary action method with Id as parameter and will invoke that action method.

You can learn about setting the routing by looking into below links

[Routing in Web core API](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/routing-in-asp-net-core-web-api/)

[Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://medium.com/quick-code/routing-in-asp-net-core-c433bff3f1a4)

[Route Constraints](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-route-constraints/)

Comment: This doesn't answer why the route with {id} is matched and not the {name} one (or why no ambiguous route error is thrown).

Comment: Yes added more details on it